# Python:Iteration over a list of sets in python class

Tags: python, set

The problem in my code is `for` loop  at `for i in self.sets:` in class pattern; the problem is as you can see the input `V=set([1,2,3,4])` so the `for` loop in class pattern performs set enumeration.

Initially the loop starts at `i=set([1]`) from `[set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([4])]` and enumerates accordingly returning `[set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4])]` and `[set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 4])]` and lastly `[set([1, 2, 3, 4])] from i=set([1]).

now the problem with the above loop is, it always starts at `i=set([1])` instead it should skip to `i=set([2]), set([3]) etc.` at the end every enumeration ends with `[set([1, 2, 3, 4])] for the above input V` for each element thus generating all possible combinations.

```
class pattern(object):
    def __init__(self,node,sets):
        self.node=node
        self.sets=sets


    def enum(self):

        for i in self.sets:
            L=[]
            print "i"
            print i
            for j in self.node:
                if i!=j:
                    if type(i) is int:
                        L.append(set([i])|set([j]))
                    else:   
                        if j not in i:
                            L.append(i|set([j]))    

            return L                

V=set([1,2,3,4])
U=[]
h=[]
num=0
for i in V:
    cnt=1
    for j in range(1,len(V)+1):
        if cnt==1 or U==list(V):
            U=[]
            for a in V:         
                U.append(set([a]))
            #print U
        else:
            p=pattern(V,U)
            h=p.enum()
```

The above pattern class must return [set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4])] for the first time it is called and [set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 4])] for the 2nd time and [set([1, 2, 3,4])] for the third time if you can observe all it returns are the enumeration of 1 with other numbers so now it should enumerate 2 with other numbers similarly as 1 did before but it is not considering 2 or 3 or 4 but every time it is considering 1 and returning sam results as above

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation is rather difficult to follow... Could you rephrase and break it up into sentences so it's not one wall of text please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to enumerate over all combinations of elements in set `V`, without replacement.  You can do that as follows utilizing the python library.

```
import itertools

def all_combinations(v):
    for i in range(len(v)):
        for c in itertools.combinations(v, i + 1):
            yield c

list(all_combinations([1,2,3,4]))
```

yields

```
[(1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Actually I know about powergen recipe but here I have to do more stuff on the return module as they are part of a graph I need to find their density and parent nodes so I have to do it this way .. anyways Thanx for the reply

Comment: @user2014111 That'd be useful information to include in questions... this answer does solve your question, but it's now unsuitable and has wasted mtadd's time answering because you didn't include you're taking the approach you are because you're doing *more stuff on the return module as they are part of the graph*... Please update your question to give a fuller picture :)

Comment: If you could, please give an example of your expected output from `pattern.enum` for a given **V** and **U**.